# Can the union of four groups of order $3$, under the same operation, form a group of order $9$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The question I’m looking at actually asks me to prove that a group $G$ of order $9$ is abelian. I’m trying to see if the arrangement above is possible, since if not I can show that $G$ is cyclic, hence abelian.

Comment: This is more easily proved by proving that any group of order $p^2$ for $p$ prime is abelian.

Comment: A group of order $9$ does not need to be cyclic. Consider for example $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: In $\mathbb Z_3\times\mathbb Z_3$ you have four subgroups of order $3$: $\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2)\}, \{(0.0), (1,1),(2,2)\},\{(0,0),(1,2),(2,1)\},\{(0.0),(1,0),(2,0)\}$, so whatever your argument looks like, it cannot be based on impossibility to have such subgroups.